# Bash : Syntax Error Near Unexpected Token `'table_name'`

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu, laravel

I'm getting started learning Laravel 5 in Ubuntu 15.04. So, I'm done creating my database but when I'm trying to insert data using Terminal, I've got some error that says

```
bash : syntax error near unexpected token `'table_name'`
```

Here's my terminal inputs in my laravel app directory

```
DB::table('table_name')->insert(['title' => 'My First Title', 'create_at' => new DateTime, 'updated_at' => new DateTime]);
```

It's just an simple queries on adding datas inside my database but I can't get through this thing. Is there any one who can help me? I've checked the other question like these but in my condition, I think its different and I couldn't find some possible solutions base on their questions.

Comment: That line needs to be in your PHP script, not the command line

Comment: Looks like a scripting language. Not bash.

Comment: No sir. They run it on the command line(terminal) and the result should be //true but instead I've receive that bash error.

Comment: What do you think sir is the best solution here? Base on Laracast, they run in on the terminal.

Comment: _"No sir. They run it on the command line(terminal)"_  Maybe.  But __not__ on a __bash__ command line(terminal).

Comment: What do you mean sir @John1024? Is there any additional command in the terminal that I have to insert or what? Thanks

Comment: The command that you show is __not__ a bash command.  If there is a command line on which it works, it will be for some other very different language.  Does Laravel have [a command line interface](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/artisan)?

Comment: Yes sir @John1024 You gave me an idea. Yes! Laravel 5 has command line interface called "artisan" so haha I forgot to call the artisan while running that inputs on my command line. It should run first "php artisan tinker" then that's the right place where I can insert my php queries. Thank you sir! I think I got it now! Please add an "Answer Question" and I'll mark it as "Answered" :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there is not a bash command.  Consequently, when entered at a bash prompt, it generates an error message:

```
$ DB::table('table_name')->insert(['title' => 'My First Title', 'create_at' => new DateTime, 'updated_at' => new DateTime]);
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `'table_name''
```

In the above, bash believes that you are trying to define a function called `DB::table`.  A function definition would typically look like: `DB::table() { cmd1; cmd2; }`.   In this form, however, bash does not expect to find a token between the open and close parens. Therefore, it generates an error message as shown above.

To execute that command, an interpreter that understands Laravel is needed.  Fortunately, there is just such an interpreter included with Laravel and it is called Artisan.  You can read more about it [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/artisan).

Comment: Yeah Sir @John, You gave me hint when you said about command line interface. Yeah I haven't enter the php artisan tinker. By the way, thank your sir! God bless

Answer (score 0):

i have also get this type error my problem solve by following below 2 step

(1)php artisan tinker
(2)DB::insert('insert into users (id, name) values (?, ?)', [1, 'Dayle']);